# Initialize a slice resource in a osgi service

Tags: slice, aem, osgi-bundle

I want to initialize a model class that is a @SliceResource into an Osgi Service.
Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In an AEM project that uses Slice, the idiomatic way to obtain a graph of objects in an OSGi service is by obtaining a reference to an Injector.

```
try (InjectorWithContext injector = InjectorUtil.getInjector(INJECTOR_NAME, resolver)) {
  final ModelProvider modelProvider = injector.getInstance(ModelProvider.class);
  MyModel myModel = modelProvider.get(MyModel.class, knownResource);
  //do something with the model
}
```

Keep in mind that this can be used not just to instantiate a class annotated with `@SliceResource` but to build an arbitrary graph of objects using [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation) as the Dependency Injection framework. It's a very powerful tool that allows you to manage all sorts of objects, possibly in different injection contexts (More information [here](https://cognifide.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SLICE/pages/360503/Scopes+of+objects))

Remember that the injector needs to be closed once you're done using it. Fortunately, the `InjectorWithContext` interface extends the `AutoCloseable` interface so you can use it in a try-with-resources block, as shown above.

Use [`InjectorUtil`](http://cognifide.github.io/Slice/apidocs/4-3-0/com/cognifide/slice/util/InjectorUtil.html) to obtain an injector. The `INJECTOR_NAME` can be found in your `Activator` where the Injector is instantiated and bindings between interfaces and implementations are registered.

`ModelProvider#get` allows you to inject a model in a context specified by the second argument. This can be a `Resource` instance or a path.